# Confirmation about pgrep returning itself

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have read several posts here about cases where pgrep 'seems' to return itself even though it never should. The key seems to be the difference between how bash and sh function. Except that in my case, I have confirmed that sh really is a link to bash.

- I'm running on SuSE 12 x86_64
- /bin/sh is a link to bash
- /bin/bash is the real binary

I have a Ruby script which calls pgrep like this:

```
  cmd="/usr/bin/pgrep -lf \"#{target}\""
  pidList=`#{cmd}`
```

I need to use the full command line because I'm actually using an argument to uniquely identify a specific 'java' process.

Now, due to some unrelated foolishness, I almost immediately do a `ps -p` on each of the pids returned. For a while, this was causing me great grief because the ps would sometimes return nothing. Eventually I was able to catch a case where the ps on the pid returned the pgrep command. But it was the pgrep command itself, not something like `sh -c "pgrep -f blah"`

To recap:

pgrep never returns itself. But differences in sh vs bash can cause it to show a subshell. But I verified that sh is a link to bash, so there should be no difference in behavior.

What I suspect (and am looking for confirmation for) is that an extra subcommand is being created because of the Ruby backticks and that is what is (only sometimes.. timing issues?) being picked up by the pgrep command.

This has been a real pain and I want to make sure the fix I implement will truly make the problem go away. Given the code I'm working with, I'm either going to

1. append a `| grep -v grep` to the end of my command
2. throw out any results containing 'grep' while looping through the returned results within the Ruby script

I figure #2 is faster, but it still irks me that I have to filter out pgrep itself.

Am I on the right track or do you think something else is at play?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: When `bash` is invoked as `sh` it behaves as a POSIX `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Ahh, that would be the missing puzzle piece! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already in the comments to my question, but I figure I'll close this out with an official answer.

The piece of information I was missing is that

> When bash is invoked as sh it behaves as a POSIX sh, not bash.  – Jörg W Mittag Jan 23 at 23:31

So yes, pgrep was behaving normally. But when you call it from a Ruby script via backticks, you still need to filter out 'pgrep'

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in shell flavor: the shell process which calls `pgrep` also shows among processes (and has the searched string in its full command), so we need to filter it out like this:

```
pgrep -f target | grep -v $$
```

Comment: This works: `if pgrep -f "debconf/frontend" | grep -v $$; then sudo pkill -9 -f "debconf/frontend"; fi`